# What is the purpose of CLI docker container, when the same commands executed within can be achieved otherwise?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The CLI container is used to run below:

1. peer create channel
2. List item
3. peer join channel
4. peer install chaincode
5. peer instantiate chaincode
6. peer invoke chaincode
7. peer query chaincode

However the same can be achieved without creating a docker CLI container.So what is the actual purpose of it?

Comment: " the same can be achieved without creating a docker CLI container " , are you sure about this ? As far as i have experimented its not possible to do stuff with chaincode/transactions without CLI (due to the fact that the Go compiler is not included in the fabric-peer image anymore which was not the case previously). The only other way is to write code from Node/Java SDK's to do the above tasks.

Do correct me if i'm wrong. :)

Comment: Yes it is possible to run all of it without creating CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hyperledger Fabric CLI (peer command) can be run natively, without a docker container. For purposes of the samples, though, we can run the whole sample in the cloud, if one wishes. It just simplifies things a bit and allows us to be more prescriptive of the environment.